# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 multiple monitor issues

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 15.10

I have a few problems since installing 15.10 on my Dell XPS 13 9343, mostly concerning multi-monitor use.

1. If the screen blanks (based on power settings), the external monitor cannot be woken up again - it remains permanently blank. My workaround is to unplug it and plug it in again.
2. I run VirtualBox and use the external monitor as a full-screen display of the VM, while keeping email, web browsing etc on the main laptop display. If I move the mouse from the VM onto the activities bar on the laptop display (for example, click on the calendar in the top bar) without clicking on any of the application windows, the display often becomes inactive. If I click on an application window first, it works properly. When it's inactive, it is quite hard to get control back. Sometimes using the "windows" key will bring it back, sometimes I have to use Ctrl/Alt/Del then cancel the shutdown dialog.

The second issue existed with 15.05 previously.

Does anyone else have similar problems or solutions?
Thanks!